Prisma recreating deleted/renamed tables
I have a project in node, with nestjs where i use prisma on.
The database used is postgres.
The problem i have is, when renaming or deleting a table trought migrations, and even directly deleting them on a software like DBeaver, they return when i restart all my containers, or restart my computer.
I renamed my table Device to Component, all goes well, the renaming is done correctly and all the data that was there before is intact.
But when i restart my containers, or my computer, the table Device reappears in a empty state, and the table Gateway keeps existing with all the data it should.
